# Subtracting days from a DateTime

Tags: php, datetime

I'll just cut to the chase here. Here is my dysfunctional code having to do with finding a start time by subtracting an interval from an end time:

```
    $timeEnd = "2015-01-08T12:53:13-05:00"; //retrieved from bot crawler
    $interval = date_interval_create_from_date_string("10 days");
    $timeEndOb = new DateTime($timeEnd);
    $timeStartOb = $timeEndOb->sub($interval);
    $timeStart = $timeStartOb->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo $timeStart;
    //echoing 2015-01-08 12:53:13
```

What's my stupid problem?

Comment: What is your input and expected output?

Comment: [Works for me](https://eval.in/240406)

Comment: My expected output is 2014-12-28 12:53:13. Exactly 10 days prior to the $timeEnd. Not sure what you mean by input. I believe all my variables are ready to mix here.

Comment: you are using php version (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0) ?

Comment: Note that `$timeEndOb->sub($interval);` subtracts `$interval` from the actual `$timeEndOb` instance, it isn't cloning a new instance for the return value

Comment: @Dagon if they used something older - they would get an error, not a wrong value though http://3v4l.org/55rdt#v5322

Comment: @MarkBaker Do you mean that it is altering the value but not returning it to my new variable?

Comment: It should return itself (for method chaining purposes) so `$timeStartOb` should simply by a reference to the original `$timeEndOb` variable

Comment: @Brimby Mark's comment was more a side note thing, it does not change the behaviour of your code. It's not possible that your script returns you what you state it returns on any known php version.

Comment: The code looks fine. The expected output should be 12-29 by the way, not 12-28, but yeah, I don't see how that could possibly be outputting 1-08.

Comment: Ok I got the issue thanks to you guys. It wasn't that it was copying timeEnd over timeStart, it was that it was altering timeEnd to be like timeStart. I had only been looking at this in a mysql table and had hardcoded everything in for this question. Thanks a bunch. Guess I should always provide actual code in a question even if it is more long-winded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) to clone object:

```php
$timeEnd = '2015-01-08T12:53:13-05:00';
$timeEndOb = new DateTime($timeEnd);
$timeStartOb = clone $timeEndOb;
$timeStartOb->modify('-10 days');
echo $timeStart = $timeStartOb->format('c');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/240458)</kbd>

or you can use [`DateTimeImmutable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php)<sup>PHP>=5.5.0</sup> class which behaves the same as `DateTime` except it never modifies itself but returns a new object instead:

```php
$timeEnd = '2015-01-08T12:53:13-05:00';
$timeEndOb = new DateTimeImmutable($timeEnd);
$timeStartOb = $timeEndOb->modify('-10 days');
echo $timeStart = $timeStartOb->format('c');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/240464)</kbd>

Comment: Great tips for this PHP noob. I ended up doing something similar to this, but shortcutted the clone step 

$timeStartOb = new DateTime($timeEnd)

Comment: @Brimby: for this example, this should work perfectly. But it will fail if you are doing some modification on `$timeEndOb` object before creating `$timeStartOb`, where `clone` clones current `$timeEndOb` instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply with the `strtotime` function and `date` function

```
$timestamp_end = strtotime("2015-01-08T12:53:13");// Note, I removed the timezone
$date_start = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-10 days', $timestamp_end));
$date_end = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp_end);
echo $date_start.' to '.$date_end;
```

2014-12-29 12:53:13 to 2015-01-08 12:53:13

Comment: Why would you remove timezone? Unix timestamp would then be invalid (it would only be valid if global timezone is set to same as input).

Comment: Honestly not sure what I was thinking by removing it. There is no reason I should have. @Glavić You're exactly write about invalid timestamps then.